# elasticsearch query with ajax

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I run a query and get a result in marvel plugin as you see in picture:[image].

And I want this in my web app with ajax request here is my piece of code

```
var query = "{'query': {'wildcard': {'heroname': {'value': '*dr*'}}}}";

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "http://localhost:9200/dota2/_search?" + query,
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        debugger
                                        alert("Success do your stuff!");
                                    },
                                    error: function (a, b, c) {
                                        debugger
                                        alert("Server Internal Error!");
                                    }
                                })
```

Its in success but returns many results.. I cant find reson of that. but I copy the request has been sent from client to elastic and paste it browser then here is json data as response comes my ajax success: 
[image]

I expect just 1 json data as seem in marvel plugin, but it returns me all datas in index so I think wildcard query ignored but why ? or etc ?

Comment: In your URL, I can see you have the question sign (i.e. `?`) twice, one before the inlined query and another one before `pretty`, so can you try again with `&pretty` instead of `?pretty`?

Comment: I edited the question with your change, but it just imprevoed response format :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass your search query in the query string in a GET call, you need to pass it in the [`source` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:9200/dota2/_search?source=" + query,
    ...                                        ^
                                               |
                                   add source parameter here
```

Comment: it throws "SearchPhaseExecutionException" here is the full exception msg:{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[P9HfL6BpRW-S61IeDUJdPw][dota2][0]: SearchParseException[[dota2][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{'query': {'wildcard': {'heroname': {'value': '*dr*'}}}}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field

Comment: Should I delete ' characters from query string ?

Comment: Yes, because you need to use escaped double quotes in your JSON string, not single quotes.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.

Comment: Hello, can you check this also? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32181301/elasticsearch-aggregations-seperated-words Thank you