# elasticsearch aggregations separated words

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I simply run an aggregations in browser plugin(marvel) as you see in picture below there is only one doc match the query but aggregrated separated by spaces but it doesn't make sense I want aggregrate for different doc.. ın this scenario there should be only one group with count 1 and key:"Drow Ranger".
What is the true way of do this in elasticsearch..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `heroname` field is `analyzed` and thus "Drow Ranger" gets tokenized and indexed as "drow" and "ranger".

One way to get around this is to transform your `heroname` field to a multi-field with an analyzed part (the one you search on with the wildcard query) and another `not_analyzed` part (the one you can aggregate on).

You should create your index like this and specify the proper mapping for your `heroname` field

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dota2 -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "agust": {
            "properties": {
                "heroname": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "raw: {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ... your other fields go here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can run your aggregation on the `heroname.raw` field instead of the `heroname` field.

**UPDATE**

If you just want to try on the `heroname` field, you can just modify that field and not recreate the whole index. If you run the following command, it will simply add the new `heroname.raw` sub-field to your existing `heroname` field. Note that you still have to reindex your data though

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/dota2/_mapping/agust -d '{
    "properties": {
        "heroname": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw: {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can keep using `heroname` in your `wildcard` query, but your aggregation will look like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "asd": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "heroname.raw",    <--- use the raw field here
                "size": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it because of my field index analyzed. but if I make this this time I may not able to make "case insensitive query". I mean I already did this, and I run query "...wildcard:*d*"... it doesnt work but *D* works.. so how is the make both of this work ?

Comment: Case insensitive wildcard search will work agaist the `heroname` field and the aggregation will work against the `heroname.raw` field. All we are doing is adding a new field (`heroname.raw`), not changing the one that already works (`heroname`). Try it out.

Comment: I understood what you mean exactly and also it works perfect!, thank you  :) Kind Regards,